# Get innerHTML from same tags

Tags: javascript, html

I am having a trouble for fetching innerHTML of the following two `strong` tags

```
<div>
    <strong>data 1</strong> 
    <span class="and">and</span> 
    <strong>data 2 </strong>
</div>
<div>
    <strong>data 3</strong> 
    <span class="and">and</span> 
    <strong>data 4 </strong>
</div>
```

i want to get `data1, data2` in console but i'm unable to achieve anything.
I have tried `document.querySelector("strong")` but it just provide me `data1`.

How can i fetch `data2 data3 & data4` from other `strong` tag?
Any help is appreciated.

i know i can do

```
document.getElementsByTagName("strong")['increment_operator'].innerHTML;
```

and

```
document.querySelectorAll("strong");
```

Comment: try `queryselectorall()`

Comment: That is because when it finds once the `element` it stops looking for other. So in this case you need `loop` to continue to response for every `element` named `strong` it finds, or try as @debin mentioned.

Comment: what strong tag do you need? From first div, second div or both ?

Comment: @AndriyIvaneyko every strong tag which appears in html DOM. this is just a sample i provided, there are random number of strong tags are generated depending upon the records available in the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok i did my job by doing following.

```
var divLength = document.getElementsByTagName("div").length;
var z = 0;
for(i=0; i<divLength; i++){
    var dataFromFirstStrong = document.getElementsByTagName("strong")[z].innerHTML;
    z++;
    var dataFromSecondStrong = document.getElementsByTagName("strong")[z].innerHTML;
    z++;
}
```

Comment: @AndriyIvaneyko i have to wait to 2 days

Answer (score 2):

querySelector finds the first result and stop searching whereas querySelectorAll finds all.

Answer (score 2):

Try code below to log html of `strong` tag:

```
var elems = document.getElementsByTagName('strong');
for (i=0;i < elems.length;i++{
  console.log(elems[i].innerHTML)
}
```

To get innerHTML of the last `strong` tag in html run code below:

```
var elems = document.getElementsByTagName('strong')[:1];
console.log(elems[elems.length-1].innerHTML);
```

Comment: i knew your solution, the data i provided was already fetched from another tag i-e from a div, now how can i use another document.getElementsByTagName('strong') from within that?

Answer (score 1):

If you have same tag and you want specific tag innerHTML then give unique ids and then try to fetch or if you want to fetch all `strong` tag innerhtml then use `queryselectorall()`

As example

```
 <div>
    <strong>data 1</strong> 
    <span class="and">and</span> 
    <strong>data 2 </strong>
</div>
<div>
    <strong>data 3</strong> 
    <span class="and">and</span> 
    <strong>data 4 </strong>
</div>

var a = document.querySelectorAll("strong");
for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
  alert(a[i].innerHTML);
}
```

Comment: i knew your solution, the data i provided was already fetched from another tag i-e from a div, now how can i use another document.querySelectorAll('strong') from within that?

Comment: What do you want exactly?? same tag innerHTML right?and what does  `document.querySelectorAll('strong') from within that` mean?

Comment: Please have a look at my updated sample data in the question.

Comment: please first try answer..by doing this you will get your desire output

Comment: yes i know it works but i do not want to loop over each strong tag i am already looping over <div> tag, so inner loop will not do any help unfortunately :(

Answer (score 0):

Summing up the partials:

1. The `document.querySelector(commaSeperatedStringOfSelectors)` only finds the first node in the `document`satisfying the selectors it is given. So you need to be more specific with it, need to supply some queryable selectors to your html elements, like `id` `class`.

But if you want to select more widely follow:

2. `document.querySelectorAll(commaSeperatedStringOfSelectors)` to get an array of all the nodes satisfying the selectors. Then you can select the element you need by index. [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/isikfsc/sky7y1cx/2/)
3. Or you need to use @Andriy Ivaneyko's answer style, use `getElementByTagName('tagname')`, `getElementsByClassName('class')`, or `getElementById('id')`.

Note: `document.querySelectorAll(commaSeperatedStringOfSelectors)` is more versatile, it gives you opportunity to be both more specific or more unspecific. You can use a string like that in it: `'strong, div.animals, a'`.